# Rotating / Twist object not in sync / Transformation Orientation along Normal

Tags: modifiers, extrude, axis

I'm trying to rotate / twist (note: the twist is used because it will be extended up in 3D to twirl around ) an object in sync but after I did an extrude on the edge using  `Transformation Orientation along Normal`

[image: img1]

strange things happened

[image: img2]

I've included the blend file and animation.  How can I sync the rotation of the arms back up?  Why did this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the plane at some point stopped being perfectly "flat" which causes problems when you twist on the Z-axis. Select the whole thing in edit mode then press <kbd>S</kbd> (scale) + <kbd>Z</kbd> (axis) + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to make it perfectly flat again. The twist should work as expected after this.

[image: Flat]